# How do write a gcc spec that adds to output files but does not append to command?

Tags: unix, gcc, specs

I am porting gcc1.27 to a Tektronix 4404 from 1983.
The assembler commands on this machine use +o=filename (no spaces) to specify output files.

So in gcc.c, the assembler spec of:

```
{!S:asm %{R} %{j} %{J} %{h} %{d2} %a %{gg:-G %g.sym}\
                      %g.s %{c:%{!o*:+o=%w%b.r}}%{!c:+o=%w%b.r}\n }
```

Results in "**+o=foo.r**" being added as an output (because of the %w marking it as output).

I want to be able to say "**%w%b.r**" to append to the output list, but not have that appended to the command.

Is there a known way of doing this or do I have to add my own new token?

Comment: Wow! Gcc version 1.27 was released in 1988 -- 36 years ago! It is unlikely anyone will provide an answer even if there is an answer. Is there some reason you aren't using the current version of Gcc to cross-compile to that ancient hardware? This seems like a situation where a lot more context is justified.

Comment: Tektronix4404 is a 68000 32-bit machine which I plan compiling gcc1.27.
While the specs of modern gcc has totally got out of hand  (creeping featurism FTW!)  I thought somebody may know a common cliche used to set output files without adding to the actual command.

Comment: What I have gone ahead and done is add a new token: %W (capital w) that works exactly like %w in marking an output but inhibits appending to the command.  Works fine,  but cannot help feeling I've reinvented something others have done before.